# Javascript: Link runs function not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am creating a BF4 weapon selector (tells you random weapons/attachments to equip), using the function below, and a link to refresh it (to run the function again), however when the link is clicked, it does not work (and there is no error in console)
Any ideas? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5duazhb6/)

Just to clarify: the text appears, and as a link, however when you click the link (which runs javascript:CreateWeapons(), it does not work, and there is no error in JSFiddle, or in javascript console)

JS:

```js
function Random(arr) {
            return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        }

       function CreateWeapons() {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = ('<a href="javascript:CreateWeapons();">' +
                'Primary: ' + Primary +
                '<br>' +
                'Secondary: ' + Secondary +
                '</a>');
            }

        var Primary = Random(["M16A4", "M16A3", "M416", "None"]);
        var Secondary = Random(["None",".44 Deagle"])
        CreateWeapons();

    // BF4 weapon chooser (using random values)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="weapons">
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're not suppose to call a function using `href` attribute, Try `onclick` attribute instead.

Comment: I changed it to `<a onclick="javascript:CreateWeapons();">` and now I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CreateWeapons"

Comment: Try creating new element and then change the innerHTML of tthat element on every click. You can check my answer. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/nzqxcoL0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Primary and Secondary weapons to change in each click, you have call Random method inside the CreateWeapons method.

Also it is not good way to use href to call js function, you can use onclick instead of that.

Here is the updated working code for you.

```
function Random(arr) {
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }

   function CreateWeapons() {
     var Primary = Random(["M16A4", "M16A3", "M416", "None"]);
     var Secondary = Random(["None",".44 Deagle"]);
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = ('<a href="#" onclick="CreateWeapons();return false;">' +
            'Primary: ' + Primary +
            '<br>' +
            'Secondary: ' + Secondary +
            '</a>');
        }


    CreateWeapons();

// BF4 weapon chooser (using random values)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and see what happens :P

Comment: on JSFiddle I'm getting the same thing as above (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CreateWeapons)

Comment: I am not sure why JSFiddle runs to error. In JSBin its working fine. Please see http://jsbin.com/wiqujehupe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you create an element and then use it's `onclick` event to call the function rather using the inline `onclick` event. Try this,

```
function Random(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

var aElement = document.createElement("a");
aElement.href="#";

function CreateWeapons() {  
    var Primary = Random(["M16A4", "M16A3", "M416", "None"]);
    var Secondary = Random(["None",".44 Deagle"]);
    aElement.innerHTML = ('Primary: ' + Primary + '<br />' + 'Secondary: ' + Secondary);
    document.getElementById('text').appendChild(aElement);
    return false;
}


aElement.onclick = CreateWeapons;
CreateWeapons();
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/nzqxcoL0/)